# Vaadin Spring Boot - There was an exception while trying to navigate to '' - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, okta

I'm using Vaadin and Spring Boot to build webapp used as registration form.

I'm getting an issue when deploying the webapp inside a Tomcat (but never when lauching directly from Intellij IDE).

The Stacktrace is :

```
2021-06-04 09:27:13.289 ERROR  [reportException] com.vaadin.flow.router.InternalServerError:97 : There was an exception while trying to navigate to ''
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.project.widget.ui.views.register.RegisterView': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.project.widget.backend.services.OktaService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=OktaService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:314) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:117) ~[vaadin-spring-12.3.3.jar:?]
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:160) ~[flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:137) ~[flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:136) ~[flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEventAndPopulateChain(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:525) ~[flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.createChainIfEmptyAndExecuteBeforeEnterNavigation(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:505) ~[flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:222) ~[flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:249) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:220) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:186) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.initializeUI(Router.java:93) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.initializeUIWithRouter(BootstrapHandler.java:1532) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI(BootstrapHandler.java:1525) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:475) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1547) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247) [flow-server-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111) [vaadin-spring-12.3.3.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:710) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:457) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) [spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) [spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) [spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) [spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) [servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.project.widget.backend.services.OktaService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=OktaService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 83 more
```

My project is basically composed of 2 views and 1 backend service class used to interact with a remote API called "Oktaservice".

Here is the code of my main view causing the issue when reaching the root page :

RegisterView

```
@PWA(name = "Project", shortName = "Project", enableInstallPrompt = false)
@Route(value = "")
@PageTitle("Project")
@CssImport("./views/widget-view.css")
public class RegisterView extends Div {

    private final LanguageSettings languageSettings = new LanguageSettings();
    private final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(WidgetCaptions.class.getName(),
            languageSettings.getCurrentLanguage());

    private final OktaService oktaService;

    private final EmailField email = new EmailField();
    private final PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
    private final PasswordField confirmPassword = new PasswordField();
    private final GenderField gender;
    private final TextField firstName = new TextField();
    private final TextField lastName = new TextField();
    private final TextField company = new TextField();
    private final TextField street = new TextField();
    private final TextField zipCode = new TextField();
    private final TextField city = new TextField();
    private final CountryField country;
    private final TextField state = new TextField();
    private final Checkbox privacy_checkbox = new Checkbox();
    private final Checkbox conditions_checkbox = new Checkbox();
```

public RegisterView(@Autowired @Qualifier("OktaService") OktaService oktaService) {
this.oktaService = oktaService;
addClassName("register-view");

```
        ///////////// For the country selector /////////////
        DefaultSchema schema = oktaService.getSchema();
        List<OneOfItem> items = schema.getDefinitions().getCustom().getProperties().getCountry().getOneOf();

        HashMap<String, String> countries = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (OneOfItem item : items) {
            String title = item.getTitle();
            String constant = item.getJsonMemberConst();

            countries.put(title, constant);
            values.add(title);
        }
        values.remove("-");
        country = new CountryField(bundle, values);
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gender = new GenderField(bundle);

        VerticalLayout page = new VerticalLayout();
        page.setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
        page.addClassName("page");

        VerticalLayout signInLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        signInLayout.setHorizontalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
        signInLayout.addClassName("mainLayout");

        signInLayout.add(createTitle(), createDescription());

        HorizontalLayout error_layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        error_layout.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
        error_layout.getStyle().set("display", "none");
        error_layout.getStyle().set("color", "#E55240");
        Icon error_icon = new Icon(VaadinIcon.INFO_CIRCLE);
        error_icon.setSize("15px");
        Span error_msg = new Span(bundle.getString("ErrorKey"));
        error_msg.getStyle().set("font-size", "14px");
        error_msg.getStyle().set("margin-left", "5px");
        error_layout.add(error_icon, error_msg);

        Button nextButton = new Button();
        nextButton.setText(bundle.getString("ContinueKey"));
        nextButton.getStyle().set("background", "#44748A");
        nextButton.getStyle().set("color", "white");
        nextButton.getStyle().set("cursor","pointer");
        nextButton.getStyle().set("margin-top", "5px");

        nextButton.setWidthFull();

        signInLayout.add(createFormLayout(), conditionsCheck(), privacyCheck(), error_layout, nextButton, footerLayout());

        MainLayout mainLayout = new MainLayout(languageSettings);
        HorizontalLayout topBar = mainLayout.getTopBar();

        page.add(topBar, signInLayout);
        add(page);

        nextButton.addClickListener(e -> {
            if (checkFormValidation()) {
                CreateUser user = createUserProfile();
                if (!oktaService.createUser(user)) {
                    error_layout.getStyle().set("display", "block");
                } else {
                    UI.getCurrent().navigate(ValidationView.class);
                }
            }
        });
    }   

    /*------------------------- design functions below -------------------------------------*/
```

And my Service class :

```
@Service("OktaService")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class OktaService {

    private HttpHeaders headers;
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String oktaApiUrl;
    private static final String SCHEMAS_API = "/meta/schemas/user/";

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(OktaService.class);

    private RestClient rs;

    @Value("${okta.tenant}")
    private String oktaTenant;

    @Value("${okta.api.token}")
    private String oktaApiToken;

    @Value("${okta.custom.url}")
    private String oktaCustomUrl;

    public boolean createUser(CreateUser user) {
        rs = new RestClient(oktaTenant);
        rs.setApiToken(oktaApiToken);

        User userCreated = rs.postCreateUser(user, false);
        if (rs.getStatus() != null) {
            if (!rs.getStatus().toString().startsWith("4")) {
                logger.info("POST:CreateUser success : " + userCreated);
            } else {
                logger.error("POST:CreateUser Error creating user " + user.getProfile().getLogin());
                return false;
            }

            User userActivated = rs.postActivateUser(userCreated.getId(), true);
            if (!rs.getStatus().toString().startsWith("4")) {
                logger.info("POST:ActivateUser + sendEmail success : " + userCreated);
            } else {
                logger.error("POST:CreateUser Error creating user " + user.getProfile().getLogin());
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public DefaultSchema getSchema() {
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders();

        oktaApiUrl = "https://" + oktaTenant + "/api/v1";

        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("Accept", "*/*");
        headers.add("Authorization", "SSWS " + oktaApiToken);

        String url = oktaApiUrl + SCHEMAS_API + "default";
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);
        ResponseEntity<DefaultSchema> responseEntity;

        try {
            responseEntity = rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, DefaultSchema.class);
            this.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCode());
            return responseEntity.getBody();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            logger.error(e.getStatusCode());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getOktaCustomUrl() {
        return oktaCustomUrl;
    }


    public void setStatus(HttpStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
```

With some research on this error I added the annotation @Autowired and @Qualifier to OktaService construction but did not change anything.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential problem could be with your Java package structure. Spring Boot does by default only look for annotated within the Java package (and it's children) that contains the `Application` class.

If your `OktaService` is in a location of your package structure, then it won't be found by default. As an example, if you have `Application` in `com.example.myapp.ui` and `OktaService` in `com.example.myapp.service`, then it won't work. If this is the case, then you can either change your package structure or set the `scanBasePackages` property in `@SpringBootApplication` to define a location that covers the entire application.

Comment: It might comes from this as OktaService is using this jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/github/lyvoc/okta-connector/ that I built and has a `Application`. But I can't remove it, it won't work then.
`scanBasePackages` to `com.project.widget` doesn't seem to fix it.